# Disable certain a11y warnings globally in sveltekit

Tags: accessibility, svelte, sveltekit

Sveltekit has very strict a11y checks, for instance you can't just add `on:click` to a div.

I can suppress it on a per-line bases, e.g.:

```html
<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-click-events-have-key-events -->
<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-no-static-element-interactions -->
<div on:click={handleClick}></div>
```

But how can I disable it globally?

Comment: Your third reason is not valid, buttons can have any size, it does not matter and the style is completely flexible. Just use a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sveltekit, a11y warnings nag you in several places.

**1. squiggles in VSCode**

In `.vscode/settings.json`, add:

```json
"svelte.plugin.svelte.compilerWarnings": {
  "a11y-click-events-have-key-events": "ignore",
  "a11y-no-static-element-interactions": "ignore"
}
```

**2. eslint**

If your build steps include running eslint in the CLI, the build can fail.

Customize this rule in your eslint config:

```json
"rules": {
  "svelte/valid-compile": ["error", { "ignoreWarnings": false }]
}
```

This will suppress non-fatal errors reported by the `valid-compile` rule, which is part of `plugin:svelte/recommended`.

**3. svelte-check**

If your build steps include running `svelte-check` in the CLI, the build can fail.

See if you're running `svelte-check` with the `--fail-on-warnings` flag. If yes, remove that flag so the warning will still show on screen, but won't raise an error.

This was quick and easy, but your codebase could deteriorate overtime, because all warnings are ignored, especially if the build pipeline runs remotely and nobody stares at the stdout. A better way is to disable things individually:

```bash
svelte-check --fail-on-warnings --compiler-warnings "a11y-click-events-have-key-events:ignore,a11y-no-static-element-interactions:ignore"
```

This is better but quite verbose, and pollutes your `package.json`. Personally, I choose to extract it to a `svelte-check.sh`, and call it from `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "check": "bash svelte-check.sh",
  ...
}
```

**4**. **`vite dev`** and **`vite build`**

Both will show warnings on screen, but still work fine. No build pipelines will fail, so there isn't a necessity to change.

But if you still want to get rid of the warnings, add this in `svelte.config.js`:

```js
const config = {
  onwarn: (warning, handler) => {
    // suppress warnings on `vite dev` and `vite build`; but even without this, things still work
    if (warning.code === "a11y-click-events-have-key-events") return;
    if (warning.code === "a11y-no-static-element-interactions") return;
    handler(warning);
  },
  kit: { adapter: adapter() },
};
```

Some people found they also needed to add similar things in `vite.config.js`, but I didn't find it necessary.

Answer (score 2):

to add to @ZYinMD answer for #4 in `svelte.config.js`

```js
const config = {
    onwarn: (warning, handler) => {
        if (warning.code.startsWith('a11y-')) return;
        handler(warning);
    }
};
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea to suppress all a11y warnings. This may work but it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/650#issuecomment-1806928309

```bash
sed -i 's/warn(pos, warning) {$/\0 if (warning.code.includes("a11y")) { return; }/' node_modules/svelte/compiler.cjs
```

This worked for me.
For those under Windows:

```
# Execute this under your project root
(Get-Content -Path "node_modules\svelte\compiler.cjs") -replace 'warn\(pos, warning\) {\$', '$& if (warning.code.includes("a11y")) { return; }' | Set-Content -Path "node_modules\svelte\compiler.cjs"
```

Ctrl-P -> Restart Svelte Language Server after patching the code

A11y is a good feature, troublesome sometimes, however. There **should** be some way that isn't that tricky for devs to disable it.

Btw any solutions other than this don't work for me.